# ASP.NET MVC How to populate ViewModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a MVC newbie and have created a simple project. I have a 2 models, 1 viewmodel and a repository. I'm wondering if I can use AutoMapper in my repository, and how I have to do this.

I have a the following Models

```
public class Project : BaseModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Customer: BaseModel {
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel is

```
public class ProjectViewModel {
    public int ProjectId { get;set; }
    public int Description { get;set; }
    public int CustomerName { get;set; }
}
```

I have a ProjectRepository with the following method:

```
public List<ProjectoverzichtItem> GetProjectoverzichtItems() {

    using (var context = _context) {

        var items = (from p in context.Project
                     join c in context.Company on p.CustomerId equals c.CompanyId
                     select new ProjectoverzichtItem {
                         ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                         Code = p.Code,
                         Description = p.Description,
                         Contractor = c.CompanyName
                     });

        return items != null ? items.ToList() : null;
    }  
}
```

Is this the right way to populate the ViewModel ?

Comment: Is it not working for you? And `items` can never be `null` (just an empty collection) so its just `return items.ToList();`

Comment: thx ! this is working for me, but I was wondering if the { select new ProjectoverzichtItem .. } could be replaced with automapper, or is this the right way to do this.

Comment: What you doing is just fine. And automapper wont help because you joining data from multiple table.

Comment: About repository classes: Is it designed to handle the CRUD methods for the MODEL classes or is it also designed to populate the VIEWMODEL classes?

Comment: Typically your repository classes are for the data models (getting and saving to the database). For mapping between data models and view models, you typically do that in the controller, or call a separate service to do it. But there no hard rules.

Comment: If project and customer are related in your database through a foreign key and if you are using an ORM like EF you could include the related object (I.e. context.Projects.Include(c=>c.Customer).Where.....) then you will be able to use automapper to create your view model.

Comment: JDBennett, thx, but it is not a foreign key.